# How can I generate a dynamic tag with Nokogiri::XML::Builder?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am looping through a set of tag names in an array, and I want to print each one using builder without resorting to the manual XML of the "<<" method.

I thought that:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|

  for tag in tags
    xml.tag! tag, someval
  end
end
```

would do it, but it just creates tags with the name "tag", and puts the tag variable as the text value of the element.

Can anyone help? This seems like it should be relatively simple, I have just had trouble finding the answer on search engines. I am probably not asking the question the right way.

Comment: BTW, is it Nokogirl or Nokogiri? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following. I added a root node as Nokogiri requires one if I'm not mistaken.

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root do |root|
    for tag in tags
      xml.send(tag, someval)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This works well even with sub-elements blocks! For example: x.send(:key) {x.val 3}

Answer (score 8):

try to use method_missing

```
 builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
   for tag in tags
     xml.method_missing(tag, someval)
   end
 end
```